# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Sprites: background-position from model

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, sprite

I have a collection of pictures 96x96 pixels. So I decided to combine them in one image and store inforamtion about margin in database. How can I set `background-poisiton` according to data in the model?
Or maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: What data are you using that is in the Model? Without knowing, there is no real way to answer this.

Comment: For example if I have a field `ImagePosition` which contains number representing margin in a sprite, how can I set it in `backroung-position`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have 1 value in the model called `ImagePosition` which holds the margin (top? left? bottom? right?) Then you would be able to do something like;

```
<span class="picture" style="background-position: @Model.ImagePosition center"></span>
```

or

```
<span class="picture" style="background-position: left @Model.ImagePosition"></span>
```

In this case, the class `picture` is used to hold all the sprit info e.g.

```
.picture{ 
    background: url([pathtoimage]) no-repeat center center; 
    width: [width]; /* set your width to what you want */
    height: [height]; /* set your height to what you want */
    display: block;
    /* add some padding, margins etc... */
 }
```

And then you are just adjusting the background position.

This solution though would only be able to adjust the vertical or horizontal position of the background if `ImagePosition` is a single value. If ImagePosition though was an object, say with a vertical and horizontal value, then you could adjust the position of the background more.

```
<span class="picture" style="background-position: @Model.ImagePosition.Horizontal @Model.ImagePosition.Vertial"></span>
```